# Do I have to update/fix my SSL certificate if I change a domain provider?

Tags: ssl, domain-registrar

I am considering move some of my domains to a company with cheaper prices.

Do I have to do anything to my SSL certificates?

Current certs are generated by `certbot` from `Let's Encrypt.`

I have never done this before and am quite new to server-side jobs. Thanks for any kind of tips.

Answer (score 0):

In general you will need to move the certificates to the new server and set them up in Apache/Nginx. For Let's encrypt it's easiest to generate the certificate again.
If you will have load balancer or geoip routing you will need to have the certificate on every accessible server. The certificates are for the service running, not for domain or provider. When buying certificate

Comment: Thanks, but I just change the domain registry, not the server. So am I safe and have no worries?

Comment: If the DNS is same, then no change required. If you changed nameserver and let's encrypt validation was agains dns record nad not acme, then you will need to validate that you migrated these records. Just register with using the same NS as before then you are safe.

Answer (score 0):

Certificates are independent from both the hosting provider and the domain registrar.